# Best segue after posting content

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift and I am curious about the best way to move from one view to another. I have a main view that is a tab on a tab bar and embedded in a navigation controller. From this main view, I am taking user content and then displaying that content on the main view. Currently I am segueing from the main view to a view that collects content and then another segue back to the main view. The only problem is that when I do this I get a back button and even if I hide the back button, I am just continuing to put screens on top of the tab. What would be the best way to transition from the view that collects content back to the main view?

Comment: Search for "unwind segues"; you can move back through the stack rather than continually presenting new view controllers

Comment: You should be opening that sequence of data entry in a modal and then dismissing the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there're 2 general ways how view controllers are shown and hidden:

1. Push in the navigation controller (either with 'Show' segue or in code `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)`. In that case the normal way to return to previous screen would be to use 'Back' navigation button. If you need to do it manually you can use `self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)` inside your view controller or use unwind segue (though I rarely see it used). If you need to come back to the very first screen in your navigation stack you can use `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)`.
2. Modal presentation (either with 'Present Modally' segue or with `self.present(viewController, animated: false)`. In that case in order to return to the previous view you have to add some close/cancel button on your screen and bind it with the code which call `self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`.

Anyway to have a full picture I'd recommend to get familiar with [Apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/navigation/) on this subject.

And if you need to pass some data between your controllers, ther're various ways to do it, like assigning it directly to a property in `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`, implementing delegate/callback interactions, implementing observers, shared back storages, etc.